# Linq- A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause in C#

Tags: mysql, linq, linq-to-sql

I am getting error when cross table operation performed as like this.

```
 var rows = from a in db_data.AsEnumerable()
                   join b in cust_data.AsEnumerable()
                   on a["SERVICE_ZIP"].ToString().Trim().ToLower() equals b["Zip"].ToString().Trim().ToLower()
                   where
                    a["SSS"].ToString().Trim().ToLower() == b["SSS"].ToString().Trim().ToLower() &&  
                    a["ttt"].ToString().Trim().ToLower() == b["ttt"].ToString().Trim().ToLower()
                   into g
                   where g.Count() > 0
                   select a;
        DataTable merged;
        if (rows.Any())
            merged = rows.CopyToDataTable();
        else
            merged = cust_data.Clone();
```

Comment: I have tried other commands, but not working

Comment: Thanks. The error is "A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause in C#"

Comment: This is *not* a "cross table operation". By calling "AsEnumerable" you force the *entire* table to be loaded in memory. Instead of a LINQ-to-SQL query that will load a few records from Table A, you have a LINQ to Objects query that has to work on two big in-memory collections that were loaded from the database. I doubt this is what you wanted to do.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. ya @PanagiotisKanavos. My goal is to load  the data in memory and compare like normal SQL operation for this as below SELECT *
  FROM data d, c_data c
  WHERE c.ZIP =d.SERVICE_ZIP
  and  c.sss        =d.sss and   c.ttt       =d.ttt.  I need to change this SQL statement to LINQ  and then output need to store in Datatable again . could you pls assist me?

Comment: LINQ isn't a replacement for SQL. Loading everything in memory is *slower* than executing the SQL statement. In fact, simply executing the loops necessary for in-memory filtering will be slower than hitting the database, because there are no indexes in memory. If you have a working SQL query, why are you using LINQ at all? If you really have to, at least create a view and map your DTO to that view

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply. Ya The thing is I tried to load the bulk data to oracle db, I am getting error  [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33909699/oracle-server-error-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connect).  so that i tried some of the solution but  that not handy, so i plan to switchover to this.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Using ADO.net I am able connect Db, but not using the SqlBulkCopy bulkInsert = new SqlBulkCopy(oracleConnectionString); thing. could you pls come gain ?

Answer (score 1):

Using the `into` clause allows LINQ comprehension expressions to be chained together, this is very powerful. But each must be a complete comprehension expression.

There is no `select` or `group` clause before the `into` in your code.